# Remove image title when mouse hover on the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lytebox

I am using lytebox for my image gallery. It works great except when a user hovers on images, there will be texts with `html` tags shown on the browser.

ex:

```
<h1>This is the first image </h1>
<p>The image desc<p>
```

I need the `title` attribute for my image gallery but don't want it to show when the user hovesr the image. Is that possible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can u post it on jsfiddle or demo on your site?

Comment: you can hide the the hover effect using css but for title you might need to change jquery.

Comment: why don't you just use alt tag instead of title then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var imgTitle;

$("img").hover(function(){
    imgTitle = $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).removeAttr("title");
}, function(){
   $(this).attr("title", imgTitle);
});
```

Comment: I think you beat me by 2 seconds.  +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to do something like:

```
$('#slideshow img').hover(function() {
    $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).attr('title', '');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/cX5MD/

You won't see the title on the img's but if you inspect them you'll see they are still there.

You could also use jQuery `removeAttr` and `attr` instead of setting it to empty string.

Comment: ty for the jsfiddle example +1. :)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple like this

```
$('img').removeAttr('title');
```